# How can I prevent using Spring Security with Thymeleaf from breaking CSS formatting?

Tags: html, css, spring-security, frontend, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf and Spring Security. I have a dropdown-menu with list items in it. Unfortunately, since the Thymeleaf + Spring Sec integration uses a div as you see below, that means that we now have ul with a div inside with a li inside. That breaks css formatting from bootsrap and less which expect ul>li. In other words, li is supposed to be a direct child of the dropdown ul but it isn't in my case because of the sec:authorize div. Here are those css dependencies: [picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nhBo.png)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu text-left">
    <li>
        <a role="button" class="a-primary btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.view"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> View</a>
    </li>
    <div sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('A_ROLE', 'ANOTHER_ROLE')">
        <li>
            <a role="button" class="a-primary btn-xs" data-bind="visible: permissions().contains('Edit'), click: $parent.edit"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Edit</a>
        </li>
        (more <li> elements in here)
    </div>
</ul>
```

So that first li displays correctly, but the li inside of the sec:authorize div doesn't format correctly.

How can I get the inner li elements to display correctly without editing the .css files that I depend on? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add your authorization in a `div`. You can use `th:block` instead, which won't create any additional element.

```
<th:block sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('A_ROLE', 'ANOTHER_ROLE')">
    <li>
        <a role="button" class="a-primary btn-xs" data-bind="visible: permissions().contains('Edit'), click: $parent.edit"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Edit</a>
    </li>
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to simply remove that outer div and instead put the sec:authorize on each li. This preserves the "dropdown-menu>li" structure that those .css dependencies expect. On the downside, it does mean that I have to put the same sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('A_ROLE', 'ANOTHER_ROLE')" on multiple li. Still, it works.

**Edit**: Nevermind, used the solution marked above.